# Remove line if doesn't contain phone number PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
;Dear UU, Share No:XXX;
0987654321;Dear TT, Share No:XXX
;Dear UU, Share No:XXX;
1234567890;Dear TT, Share No:XXX
```

I want this string like this

```
 0987654321;Dear TT, Share No:XXX
 1234567890;Dear TT, Share No:XXX
```

How to remove the line that does not contain phone number (`1234567890` and  `0987654321` are phone numbers here) in `php`

I getting those lines from foreach() loop and if it has a phone number, the script will send SMS to those number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regular expression `/^\d{10}.*$/` to match your string.

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{10}.*$/", "0987654321;Dear TT, Share No:XXX")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: @priyamanu If this answer works for you then mark this as accepted. So, it build trust to other while adapting regular expression.

Comment: Thank you. Another question., what if i have  sting like `the price is 500 for`, `the price is for`, `the price is 250 for` and I have to remove `the price is for` line (which does not contain 500 or 250 or other values)?

Comment: @Priyamanu follow this link. http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/gla_42/ref/rregexp.html and prepare expression according to your need.

Comment: Simply did not understand regexp. Please help me.

Comment: @Priyamanu here is your regex. `/.*\d{3}.*$/` It check 3 digit in a string.